How to Adjust Font Size in Kibana Dashboard After Upgrading from 7.10 to 7.17
After upgrading Kibana from version 7.10 to 7.17, we noticed several changes in the dashboard's appearance. In Kibana 7.10, we used a template that is no longer compatible with Kibana 7.17. One specific issue we're facing is with the font size. In Kibana 7.10, the font size was set to 12px, but in Kibana 7.17, it has increased to 14px.
How can we adjust the font size to 12px in Kibana 7.17 or kibana 8.3.4 same problem to readapt the visualization of our dashboard? Where can we find the relevant file on the server to make this change?
Thank you for your help!
